# Filtering ".." and "." with QDir?

Tags: qt4

Other than filtering the `..` and `.` manually, is there an "official" way to do that?

The document didn't mention much, here's what I use,

```
QDir dir (path);
foreach (const QFileInfo & fileInfo, dir.entryInfoList())
{
  if (fileInfo.fileName() != ".." && fileInfo.fileName() != ".")
  {
     blabla
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` option of `entryInfoList`:

```
foreach (const QFileInfo & fileInfo, dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files))
```

(which will give you only the files: add `QDir::Dirs` for the directories)